# passing isset on everything

Tags: php, isset

I am maintaining a codebase which many people are working on. I have a situation where a function is being passed with needs to have isset passed and checked on all items before it returns. Instead of me adding an isset for each setProperty as is in foo_item2 example, is there a way to make it apply to all setProperty calls?

```
function &someFooFunction($row, $details = true) {           
$foo = new otherFooItem();
$foo->setProperty($row['foo_item1']);           
if (isset($row['foo_item2'])) {      
$foo->setProperty($row['foo_item2']);      
}      
$foo->setProperty($row['foo_item3']);      
return $foo;      
}
```

I keep adding if (isset($row['foo'])) { for each line and there are 100's of lines.

Comment: I don't get it. What does setProperty do? Assign just a single property's value? Or adds to array?

Comment: either way, you can list all required item names in array, and then just loop over it

Comment: Does `setProperty` need to know which field you are setting rather than just the value?

Comment: setProperty assigns a value from a call. its just a value from mysql backend.  

The problem with using an array is, foo_item keeps changing all the time. More items keep getting added or removed and no one tells me. 

Is there a way to move the isset call further up the object calls so I don't need to keep adding them in function.

yes, setProperty needs to know the field. Its  colum in a db.

Comment: You could change the function call to take the row and an array key, and do the isset inside of the function. `$foo->setProperty($row, 'foo_item1')`